# Datos Relacionados - Net Core 2.1

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

Desarrollando una WebAPI bajo NetCore en su versión 2.1 y EFCore donde tengo la siguiente relación de entidades.

```
public partial class A
{ 
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public string IdA { get; set; }


    public virtual ICollection<B> B{ get; set; }     
}

public partial class B
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public string IdB { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<C> C{ get; set; }
}

public partial class C
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public string IdC { get; set; }
}
```

Ahora bien, en una misma consulta al contexto de datos quiero obtener los datos de C, pero esta colección es siempre null bajo la siguiente consulta.

```
var consulta = await _context.as.Include(z => z.A).ThenInclude(z=>z.B.Select(z=>z.C)).FirstOrDefaultAsync(z => z.IdA == id);
```

Como podrían obtener los datos de la propiedad "ICollection C" mediante una consulta de este estilo.

Gracias.

Comment: como define la clase que implementas el DbContext el mapping de esta relacion? intentaste analizar el sql que se genera viendo el Sql Profile, que seria esto de _context.as ? de donde sale ese "as"

Comment: es el contexto de datos, siendo as la tabla de donde obtengo los datos de la entidad A

Answer (score 4):

Parece que armaste y configuraste mal las relaciones de las clases... por lo general este tipo de errores es por ese motivo.

Puedes armar la jerarquía de clases de la siguiente forma

```
public class ClassA
{
  public int Id { get; set; }

  public List<ClassB> B{ get; set; }     
}

public class ClassB
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public ClassA A { get; set; }

  public List<ClassC> C{ get; set; } 
}

public class ClassC
{
  public int { get; set; }
  public ClassB B { get; set; }
}
```

Cada una es una relación de uno a muchos y fíjate que en cada nivel inferior hay una referencia al superior.

Luego en el contexto indicas las relaciones:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ClassA>().HasMany(s => s.B).WithOne(s => s.A);
modelBuilder.Entity<ClassB>().HasMany(s => s.C).WithOne(s => s.B);
```

Y por ultimo realizas la consulta:

```
List<ClassA> as = context.ClassesA
  .Include(x => x.B)
    .ThenInclude(x => x.C)
  .ToList();
```

Por otro lado, cual es tu necesidad de tener clases de entidad que sean `parcial`, primary key del tipo string y los `ICollection` como `virtual`?

EntityFramework Core toma las propiedades `Id` como PK al generar la tabla en el Migration por default. Solo es necesario utilizar `[key]` cuando no sigue el estandard, pero recomiendo utilizarlo para facilitar el mantenimiento a futuro (posiblemente por otros equipos).

Answer (score 3):

Si analizamos la documentacion

[Carga de datos relacionados](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/ef/core/querying/related-data)

No deberias necesitar usar el `Select` para llegar hasta `C`, debrias hacerlo usando `ThenInclude` y luego otro como en el ejemplo

```
var blogs = context.Blogs
    .Include(blog => blog.Posts)
        .ThenInclude(post => post.Author)
        .ThenInclude(author => author.Photo)
```

arma una cascada de include que necesita obtener

pero ademas no veo en `B` la propiedad que obtenga una clase `A` en el articulo lo ejemplifica cuando define

```
public class Student : Person
{
    public School School { get; set; }
}

public class School
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<Student> Students { get; set; }
}
```

como observas `School` obtiene una lista de estudiantes, pero en la clase `Student` tienes la propiedad que accede a ese en particular, porque esto despues la mapea

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<School>().HasMany(s => s.Students).WithOne(s => s.School);
}
```

definiendo la relacion `uno a muchos`

Comment: He probado previamente con .ThenInclude pero ahí esta el problema, el segundo thenInclude reporta null en la Propiedad C de la clase B en la consulta